# Is it possible to push messages to Kafka from Google Dataflow?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there any way to connect Kafka as sink in Google Dataflow? I know we can use CloudPubSubConnector with pub/sub and Kafka, but I dont want to use Pub/sub in between Dataflow and Kafka.

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (assuming you are using Java SDK). See 'Writing to Kafka' with usabe example in JavaDoc for KafkaIO :  https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.3.0/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java#L221

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing DataFlow jobs in Python you can use Confluents Kafka client 
[https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python][1]
and write you own Beam Sink/Source interface. There is a guide for writing your own sinks/sources in Beam [https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-custom-io/][1]